# How to represent an arbitrary vector with left and right eigenvectors of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $\varphi_i$ and $\psi_i$ are respectively right and left eigenvectors of a matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. After I normalize $\varphi_i$ and $\psi_i$ so that $\psi_i^\mathsf{H}\varphi_j=\delta_{ij}$ (the Kronecker delta), it seems that any vector $v\in \mathbb{C}^n$ can be written as
$$v=\sum_{j=1}^n(\psi_j^\mathsf{H}v)\varphi_j$$
where I denote by $\mathsf{H}$ the conjugate transpose.

Intutively, I think this is wrong but this is verified by MATLAB. So how to prove this?

Comment: Kindly show attempt and what is the context.

Comment: Write $v$ as a sum of the $\varphi_j$ and multiply the result with $\psi_i^\text{H}$ on the left to find the coefficients.

Comment: @F_M_ homie u r right.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\varphi_i$ are linearly independent, we can write
$$v=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\varphi_j,\qquad \forall v\in \mathbb{C}^n.$$
Multiplying $\psi_i^\mathsf{H}$ to both sides, we have
$$\psi_i^\mathsf{H}v=\psi_i^\mathsf{H}\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\varphi_j=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\psi_i^\mathsf{H}\varphi_j=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\delta_{ij}=a_i.$$
Hence,
$$v=\sum_{j=1}^n (\psi_j^\mathsf{H}v)\varphi_j,\qquad \forall v\in \mathbb{C}^n.$$